# Re-render (reload) router-outlet in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have Angular 5 and have an issue with re-render (reload) router-outlet.
I have a links `http://example.com/:unit/home/somethingElse`. In the header, I have a switcher to change `unit`. And when it's happening I need retrieve new data from a server and put it to the header, home page and a footer(I have `http` methods in `ngOnInit` in those components). When I change `unit` (url) the data remains unchanged.

I tried to use:
`this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;` It works.
But it re-renders my header and footer each time when I navigate to others pages.

I know that I can use in `this.activatedRoute.params.subsribe()` and put there all my `http` methods, but for implementing this workaround I need to rewrite a lot of code.

Is there a way to re-render (reload) specific `router-outlet` when I want? Could you help me.

Comment: When you say `the data remains unchanged` it implies to many possible reasons. It could be the resolvers, it could be change detection, it could be a bug. Provide the source code needed to understand the problem.

Comment: I am retrieving data in `ngOnInit` and those components already rendered so `ngOnInit` runs only one time. I know that if the dynamically url changed it should be re-rerender but if it happens in the same module and routing. But I have dynamically url in the first level of nesting modules and those components where I retrieve data in the third level.

Answer (score 0):

If using `shouldReuseRoute = () => false` works for you then general approach would be to create a custom `RouteReuseStrategy`. In `shouldReuseRoute`, you can check if route params are different for the same route components, and if yes then return false, i.e. something like this:

```
if (future.component === curr.component) {
  if (curr.paramMap.keys.length) {
     const diff = curr.paramMap.keys.filter((key) =>
       curr.paramMap.get(key) !== future.paramMap.get(key));
     if (diff.length) { return false; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work as I am expecting. Header and Footer are re-rendering every time after navigation to other pages.

Comment: @MaksymKrugliachenko what URLs of those pages look like? Not sure how routes are structured in your app. I meant that if you go from `:unit/home/somethingElse` to another route `some/other/route` and if this route has been visited before than route state should be preserved with a custom strategy like above, but you hit the same page `:unit/home/somethingElse` with a different unit param than it will rerender. I am using a similar approach in my app.